# Hanging query with JSON type

Tags: db2

I'm doing a complex JSON select query in DB2, and sometimes, the query stays hang-up.
It is always the same query and it doesn't matter of the number of record processed.

Just would like to know if someone had already this kind of problem ? maybe some solutions ?
either it seems to me to be a DB2 Bug with JSON.
Not sure if I have to change the DDL of this table to make this working ? or change some DB Parameters ?
The structure of the Query is like this

```
select  json_object (
   'pppp' value json_object ( 
                                   )  format json,
   'uuuu' value json_object (  'jjjj' value 
                                           json_array 
                                          (  json_object('type' value 'jjjj', 'value' value jjjjjj  )  format json ) format json
                                           )     format json,
   'yyy' value json_object ( 
   'xxx' value json_object ( 

                                      format json        absent on null
                                   )   format json   
                                   )  format json   
    absent on null)  as JsonID
from TABLE
```

Thank You -

Comment: Please tag your question with the DB2 you really use db2-400 or db2-luw.

Comment: Ask your DBA to monitor the database for lock waits.

Comment: Well the DBAs are still looking  at this.. What I say is if I put a FETCH FIRST xxx ROWS ONLY. It stay stuck between 1000 and 1500 rows. In other Databases, I don;t have this problem then I suppose it is something to do with a Parameter or the DB Or something like this